# How to query the data WHERE the date (y) is only within 7 days before or after of date (x)

Tags: sql, where-clause

I do have a list of data. 1 column has set of dates (x) and another column with a set of dates (y).

I want to query only the data where the date (y) is only within 7 days before or after of date (x).

How would the WHERE clause look like in this case?

I tried
`WHERE date(y) between date(x) and date_add(x interval 7 day)`
but it didn't work

Thank you.

Comment: You can simply also use INTERVAL with negative values, see https://dbfiddle.uk/vhQKZOC_

Comment: date(y) - 7 < date(x) OR date(y) +7 > date(x)

Comment: Thank you Jonas. The thing with date(x) and date(y) is it is different from row to row, so can I do SELECT DATE_ADD("column name", INTERVAL -7 DAY)?

Comment: A where clause always checks row per row, so this is no problem. Just extend your where clause and write something like "date(y) between date_add(x, interval -7 day) and date_add(x, interval 7 day)"

Comment: Thank you! I tried that but I got this error. "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 35:73 extraneous input 'day' expecting ) near ',' in select expression line 35:123 cannot recognize input near 'interval' '7' 'day' in select expression". I wonder if INTERVAL works in Hive SQL ?